# Display spring model list as simple fields

Tags: java, forms, spring, jsp, tags

It is possible to bind a List of String (List) and display them in a jsp in a combo box like this:

```
<form:select path="countryId">
    <form:option value="" label="Please Select"></form:option>
    <form:options items="${countryList}" itemValue="countryId" itemLabel="countryName"/>
</form:select>
```

I want this list to display in `<td>` or `<form:input>` like fields, not in combo box.

I am binding String list in model as

```
Map referenceData = new HashMap();
referenceData.put("OutputsList", Outputs);
```

In JSP I use

```
<c:forEach var="OutputsList" items="${Outputs}">  
    ${OutputsList}
</c:forEach>
```

But list is not printed. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a wrong approach while using it in a jsp. From the code in question just swap **OutputsList**

```
Map referenceData = new HashMap();
referenceData.put("OutputsList", Outputs);
```

*In JSP I use*

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${OutputsList}">  
    ${item}
</c:forEach>
```

It will work.

Answer (score 3):

do it that way.

```
<c:forEach var="country" items="${countryList}">
  <tr>
    <td>${country.countryId}</td>
    <td>${country.countryName}</td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

and on the server side use ModelAndView object

```
List<Country> countryList;
ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index");
mv.addObject("country",countryList);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I modified my question. Please have a look on it again.